# I am making a rubiks cube and cant figure out how to get the pieces to move correctly

Tags: modeling, mesh

I can't get the Rubiks cube cubes to rotate and translate the right way without excessive animation and I'm wondering if there is some way to assign the cubes/pieces a certain path that they can follow but can't leave

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Local rotation is your friend!

Here's what I'd do:

1. create an 'Empty' at the very center of your cubes
2. snap the 3d cursor to that Empty:

[image]

3. Set the pivot point to '3d cursor':

[image]

4. Choose 'Local' rotation mode:

[image]

Then select your face cubes and rotate, using axis-constrained rotation (i.e. only one axis at a time).  If you use Local mode it shouldn't matter what crazy orientation your cube is in, your rotation will occur *relative* to the rotation of the cube:

[image]

If you rotate using the 3d Manipulator, it'll stay in Local mode as long as you don't change that dropdown.  If you use hotkeys, press the axis TWICE to be in local mode.  That is, press 'R', then 'X' once, then 'X' *again*, to rotate around the X-axis in local mode.  You can see in my image those red lines shooting out of the faces that show the axis of rotation.

Hope this helps!